# Angular 2 - PrimeNg multiple instance of object

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng, angular-ng-if

I experiencing a bug on my angular 2 project. Every object using *ngIf seems to be affect.

- DropDown : The option multiply themselves `onclick` 
  [image]

The first one doesn't multiply the option. Selectedcrops contains the result of the first dropdown.

```html
<div class="ui-g ui-gBloc">
    <div class="ui-g-12"><p-dropdown class="ui-dropdown-spec" placeholder="{{'SELECTCROP' | translate}}" [options]="cropsDD" [(ngModel)]="selectedCrops" (onChange)="DataBindingTableC($event)" ></p-dropdown></div>
</div>
<div class="ui-g ui-gBloc">
    <div class="ui-g-12"><p-dropdown class="ui-dropdown-spec" *ngIf="selectedCrop !== 'Other'" placeholder="{{'SELECTAPP' | translate}}" [options]="selectedCrops" [(ngModel)]="selectedApplication" (onChange)="DataBindingTableA($event) " [disabled]="completeCrop"></p-dropdown></div>
</div>
```

- html block : Depending on the option selected in my dropdown a different bloc 
  of html must be displayed, if I change the selected option both html bloc will 
  be displayed and so on.[image]

  - Image : I got 2 images, one is a French version and one is an English version 
    depending on language by url. Only one of them should be displayed. Witch is 
    the case on first loading. But if I change language and reload I got two 
    images and so on.[image]

What I tried:

- I update my angular/primeNg
- Clear npm package (node.js)
- Delete the `dist` folder

I got a preprod version of it who works fine, the only thing different on this version is some css modification. 
Thank you !

Comment: Can you reproduce this on plnkr?  Without some code to look at, images are not going to help us help you very much.

Comment: I roolBack to my previous stable version but still the same weird mess ! I now sure the problem won't come from the code !

Comment: Would really help if you could duplicate the issue on Plunker.  You can use [this one](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qi2Nw2imLpDUF8NJinYw?p=preview), just Fork it so your changes are on it

Comment: Thx for your help, the problem was with angular V4.3.0. I downgrade to "~4.2.6" and problem solved ! I still don't know why 4.3.0 messed things up !